# Facebook API for iOS: Autocomplete facebook group member name

Tags: ios, facebook

Facebook API for iOS: 
Is the an api for autocompleting facebook group member's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Search API to search for groups: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

As long as you don't call that endpoint on every single keyboard click, it may be a good option. It is most likely the only option anyway. You could use a timer to use the API when the user did not enter anything for 1-2 seconds, for example. Not sure if this is practical though, because every API call takes a short amount of time.

Comment: I see you can search for a group and you can search for a user. But can you search for a user in a group? Or should I have a custom server in between and store there all the members?

Comment: no, i dont think you can search for a user in a group. that would require custom coding, but i doubt it is allowed to store all group members - for privacy reasons.